# bash: /bin/myscript: permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I've added my folder's path to the bashrc, in linux mint 15. Which contains my scripts. My scripts supposed to work like the bash scripts, as I know. But every time I try to use one of my scripts the following error appears: `bash: /bin/myscript: permission denied`

And this is the export line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/peter/myscripts/
```

I logged in as root.

Comment: Uhm, are you (erroneously) putting "#!/bin/myscript" in the shebang lines of your scripts? Can you make a simple example script that does "echo hello" so we can see both what the script looks like and how you invoke it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might have forgotten to give your scripts execution permissions:

```
chmod a+x /path/to/the/script
```

Comment: Why would the error be "/bin/myscript" then instead of "/home/peter/myscripts/myscript"?

Comment: I reckon erbal has not revealed the entire scenario - from the error it seems he also has a file called /bin/myscript which has not been set to execute and when he exports out the path it the call is to myscript which it finds first in /bin/